# How to load 2 embedded dlls?

Tags: c#

I have two dlls (`xNet.dll` and `ag.dll`), which I want to use in my project.

I add them to resourses, stated that build action is Embedded Resource.
Next I have such code to load the first dll:

```
public Form1()
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += AssemblyResolve;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    string assemblyName = args.Name.Split(',')[0];

    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Yandex.dll.xNet.dll"))
    {
        if (stream == null)
            return null;

        byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
    }
}
```

How to load the second dll?

Answer (score 0):

You should match on the requested assembly name and return the correct assembly.

I don't know your assembly names so i'm doing only a very simple matching but it should look something like :

```
private static Assembly AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.Name.Contains("xNet"))
    {
        return LoadAssemblyFromResource("Yandex.dll.xNet.dll");
    } 

    if (args.Name.Contains("ag"))
    {
        return LoadAssemblyFromResource("ag.dll");
    }

    return null;
}

private static Assembly LoadAssemblyFromResource(string resourceName)
{
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

    using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        if (stream == null)
            return null;

        byte[] rawAssembly = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream.Read(rawAssembly, 0, (int)stream.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(rawAssembly);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not extract the dll's to a temporary path and then load them.Assume you've two dll's,namely **firstDll** and **secondDll** with both having build action set to Resource.

Then extract those dll's to a temporary path,like this;

```
byte[] firstAssembly=Properties.Resources.firstDll;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\firstDll.dll",firstAssembly);

byte[] secondAssembly=Properties.Resources.secondDll;
File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Temp\secondDll.dll",secondAssembly);
```

After this use Reflection to load those assembles and work with them.